# JSON.parse() returns [object Object] (Node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-modules

I have been working on a node module for quite some time now and realized that if I wanted a synchronous and asynchronous function, I would have to make a different way to call the function.

Right before I call the callback function, if I console.log it, it works fine and outputs as an object. Logging the typeof also says that it is an object. However, as soon as it gets to the other side, to the test.js file, It always outputs as

> [object Object]

If I log the typeof, it says that it is an object. If I attempt to log any value of it, it won't work. An array of two objects outputs like this

> [object Object],[object Object]

It works correctly if I use JSON.stringify(), but I would like to output it as parsed.

Note: I am still able to access the values in the file.

CODE:

test.js (My test file)

```
var val;
instances.findInstance(config, function(err, res){
 if (err){
   arkin.error(err);
 }
 val = res;
});

console.log('\n\nOUT\n' + val.failures[0].failure);
```

index.js (The file which the functions will be in)

```
module.exports.findInstance = async function(config, callback){
  var returned = instances.find(config);

  const errorJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/error.json', 'utf8'));

  end(); //Deletes the JSON files

  if (globalError === true){
    let err = new Error(JSON.stringify(errorJson));
    if (!err){
      err = 'An unknown error occured';
    }
    returned = undefined;
    callback(err, returned);
  }else{
    let err = undefined;
    callback(err, returned);
  }
}
```

main.js (Previous index.js. Snippet that handles the returns)

```
  //RESULTS
  let result = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./results.json', 'utf8'));

  if (globalError === true){
    return 'ERROR';
  }else{
    return result;
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does the `error.json` file look like? Can you please edit your question to include an example?

Comment: Also, why are you mixing an `async` function with a callback?

Comment: @Soviut, the error.json file looks like this: `{"errorBool": false}` unless there is a custom error, in which case it would look like this: `{"errorBool": true, "msg": 'A string'}` (I will edit my question as well). Also,this is my first time attempting to create an `async` function, so I'm experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

I have a small answer, i.e., we use `JSON.parse()` to parse the string.

The data comes from the web server is always a string. To convert that into an object we use this parse method.

But in your issue, I think that There is nothing coming from the server. If there is no data coming from the server, then this `JSON.parse()` the method returns the default parameters. i.e., `[Object Object]`.

This is my point of view. Please check once.

Comment: What does *"If there is no data coming from the server"* mean in reality? `JSON.parse('')` (empty string) does not return `[object Object]`. What "default parameters'' are you referring to here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `console.dir` for viewing the properties of an object.

MDN [console.dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir)

> Displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object. The output is presented as a hierarchical listing with disclosure triangles that let you see the contents of child objects.